# Generating Max value from column which depends upon the range of another column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large dataset as given below:

```
 35.7337  408  0.5 
 35.732  407  0.5 
 35.7301  406  0.5 
 35.7281  405  0.5 
 35.7259  404  0.5 
 35.7236  403  0.5 
 35.7212  402  0.5 
 35.7187  401  0.5 
 35.7162  400  0.5 
 35.7136  399  0.5 
 35.711  398  0.5 
 35.7085  397  0.5 
 35.706  396  0.5 
 35.7036  395  0.5 
 35.7013  394  0.5 
 35.6992  393  0.5
```

Now, I would like to get max value of column1; only among the values whose column2 is less than 400 and also Max value of column1 whose column2 is greater than 400. There are no negative values in column 2 and column1. column 2==400 is not required as the expected outcome shall be far away from $2==400.

So my desired output

```
35.7136 (second column value <400)

35.7337 (second column value > 400)
```

Comment: and what about column 2 == 400? Can there be negative numbers in column 1? Please [edit] your question to answer this. This should be easy to implement with `awk`. Hints: use conditions like `$2 < 400` to implement different calculations for all cases, print the results in `END`

Comment: what is the delimiter? space or tabs?

Comment: Does "column 2==400 is not required" mean that rows with this value should be ignored if any?

Comment: @newstudent Please add all clarification to the question. I asked about negative numbers in column 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User [`csvsql` from `csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.5/scripts/csvsql.html):

```
csvsql -HS -d' ' --query 'select max(a) from file where b<400' file
```

For tab separated content, use `-t` instead of `-d' '`

---

or `awk`:

```
awk '
    $2<400 && $1>max1{max1=$1}
    $2>400 && $1>max2{max2=$1}
    END {printf "%s (second column value < 400)\n%s (second column value > 400)\n",max1,max2}
' file
```

If column 1 can be negative, you have to initialize `max1` and `max2`, because if it unset, max1 equals zero for `$1>max1`.

Comment: For other users with a similar problem it might be good to add a note that the conditions `$1>max1` won't work for negative numbers in column 1 because the initial empty value compares like 0.

Comment: @pLumo Can you suggest how to repeat the above script for several files? as file* gives me the result from last file.-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Tested and worked fine

command

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}($2 < 400 && $1 > sum){sum=$1}END{print sum}' filename;awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}($2 > 400 && $1 > sum){sum=$1}END{print sum}' filename
```

output

```
35.7136
35.7337
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs filter '$2 < 400' then stats1 -a max -f 1 data
35.713600

$ mlr --nidx --repifs filter '$2 > 400' then stats1 -a max -f 1 data
35.733700
```